# While driving, when I release the gas, it stays at 1500 rpm

Tags: engine, audi, a4

When I give gas while my car(Audi A4 2.0TDİ 2011) is stationary, there is no problem, the revs immediately drop to 1000. However, when I take my foot off the gas while driving, the rev counter stays at 1500. I connected it to the computer and had it checked, but nothing came up. What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How long does it stay at the stated RPM? If you do this at 3000 RPM, does it stay there? If you do this at 3000 RPM and it slows down, does it get to 1500 and stay there?

Comment: It stays at only 1500 rpm for a while. When you press the brakes, it drops to 1000 after a while. It only does this when I go above 1500 rpm.

Comment: Unless this is new behavior, I'd suggest there's nothing wrong. It seems to me that your vehicle is just coasting ... but I don't really know for sure.

Comment: The video of the problem in my vehicle is available at this link. https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Ma7citw54o4